# Create Rails App With Existing MySQL Database Without Losing Data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have a MySQL Database named `Foo_development`. It has one table, named `bars`.

```
$ mysql -e 'select * from Foo_development.bars'

+----+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name  | email         | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Alice | Alice@bob.com | 2015-08-24 13:45:11 | 2015-08-24 13:45:11 |
+----+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I'd like to create a Rails app that uses this database and this table. So I created an app and a model:

```
$ rails new Foo -d mysql
$ cd Foo
$ rails generate model Bar name:string email:string
```

That all worked just fine, although I had to edit `config/database.yml` to connect to the appropriate MySQL host before generating the model.

I tried running my app and got an error:

```
$ rails server

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:
    bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

I tried running the migrations and got another error:

```
$ rake db:migrate

== 20150824204923 CreateBars: migrating ===
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
Mysql2::Error: Table 'bars' already exists
```

Didn't know what to do here, so I tried something I found on Google:

```
$ rake db:migrate:reset

== 20150824204923 CreateBars: migrated (0.0124s) ===
```

But now all my database data is gone :(

```
$ mysql -e 'select * from Foo_development.bars'

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

**What should I have done instead to avoid losing all of my data?**

I'm assuming there must be some command besides `rake db:migrate:reset` that would allow me to run the migrations without truncating the tables in the database, but I haven't found any.

I did look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4597570/3211197) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14680873/3211197) [but](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29571311/3211197) [they](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17299232/3211197) [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16928497/3211197) [talk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11024673/3211197) about preventing data loss, so this is not a duplicate.

If it matters, the Rails app is running from a different computer than the one which hosts the MySQL database. I'm trying to avoid import/export operations, because the databases that I'm working with (outside of this trivial example) have a million+ rows, but I suppose I'm willing to do that if that's the fastest method.

*Edit:* This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25090643/3211197) is similar, but it asks about sqlite3 and the answer involves importing the database from an external file (and I'm guessing there's a faster/more efficient way than that.)

Comment: Hi @mchenja! Were you able to resolve your question?

Comment: Haven't tried yet; still hoping for a solution that doesn't require importing/exporting.

Comment: Then you can copy the `db/*` folder to your new app. then run a rails server. that should be ok

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - where would I get this folder from? There is no "old" app

Comment: sorry I touch Foo_development was from a rails app. Then I think @They_Call_Me_Joe offers a great solution. But you will need to export/import. Cause you won't be able to do it straight. Rails require a **migrations** table that will contains all the version of your db.  Unless that you create manually this table, add a content to it, and create also manually a `schema.rb` file

Comment: @PapoucheGuinslyzinho there's no way to create the migrations table automatically without deleting/truncating existing tables?

Answer (score 1):

In your first Rails app (the old one) you can add the gem `seed_dump` https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump  in your Gemfile then `bundle install`

then run in `rake db:seed:dump db:drop` that will dump the content of your database in your `db/seed.rb` file and that will also drop your db. Then you can copy and paste this file into your new Rails app under `db/seed.rb`.

```
`rake db:create`#create the db (database.yml)
`rake db:migrate db:seed`
```

So at the end you recreate a db with the same content. `Notes` if you want only one table you can use `rake db:seed:dump MODELS=Bar`

#### edit

First check to see if you have the program mysqldump installed on your machine

```
which mysqldump
```

If so then

```
mysqldump your_database_name > output.sql
```

In your rails app

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Make sure that you **drop** the db either by `rake` or by `sql syntax`.

open the file `output.sql` and **add** the line that start with `INSERT INTO bars....` in your `db/seeds.rb``with this following syntax.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `friendly_id_slugs` VALUES (3,'abram-s-commitment-to-a-life-of-faith',1,'Book',NULL,'2015-08-27 01:50:39'),(4,'what-aileth-thee',2,'Book',NULL,'2015-08-27 01:50:39');"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Notes you might have to edit your `sql` variables to use proper `apostrophe ' or "`. You could also `rails c -s` and execute the above code manually to see if it works on the `sandbox console`

Then finally

```
rake db:seed
```

Comment: I did try this, but unfortunately the `seed_dump` gem doesn't keep track of id's for each model. [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump/issues/87)

Comment: Ok look at my **edit** ... if it works. I will delete the first part of my answer... the one before the **edit**. I do prefer the **seed_dump** gem not to take track of my **id** number.

Comment: I actually think both parts of your answer are useful, so I wouldn't delete anything if I were you. But I will try it!

Answer (score 1):

A simple option would have been to put your `CreateBars` migration version number into the `schema_migrations` table.

It appears that the migration file that was causing trouble is probably named `db/migrate/20150824204923_create_bars.rb`, right?

So you could have done this in your database since the table was already there:

```
INSERT INTO schema_migrations(version) VALUES('20150824204923');
```

Oh, and I suppose you'd probably need to create the `schema_migrations` table too since Rails probably hadn't done that either:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema_migrations(
  version VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would export the tables in the database as a .csv file, depending on the language, framework, etc. you are using it is done in different ways.

Then you could fill your database seeds in your rails application from that csv file.

There are several gems that do that, please find a great one below:

https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

Answer (score 0):

As there is only one table, the easiest way would be to take a backup of the database. Create the app, create new migrations, then restore the table from the backup.